# No Project matches the given query

Tags: django, django-forms, http-status-code-404

First of all, I surely know that I do have a Project that matches the given query, so I do not understand this error. Here we go.

I have these two patterns in my urls.py, one for creation and other for edition:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^(?P<project_id>[A-Z0-9_a-z]+)/add_test_setup/$', add_test_setup, name="add_test_setup"),
    url(r'^(?P<project_id>[0-9]+)/testSetup/(?P<testsetup_id>\w+)/edit/$', add_test_setup, name="edit_test_setup"),
)
```

This is the equivalent view:

```
def add_test_setup(request, project_id, testsetup_id=None):

    project = get_object_or_404(Project, pk=int(project_id))

    if testsetup_id != None:
        testsetup = get_object_or_404(TestSetup, pk=int(testsetup_id))
        testsetupform = TestSetupForm(request.POST or None, instance=testsetup)

        if request.method == "POST" and testsetupform.is_valid():
            testsetupform.save()
            return redirect("/projects/"+testsetup.project.ref+"/info/#tabr2", testsetup.project.ref)

        else:
            return render_to_response('projects/edit_test_setup.html', {'testsetupform':testsetupform,'project':project}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

    else:
        testsetupform = TestSetupForm(request.POST or None)

        if request.method == "POST" and testsetupform.is_valid():
            testSetup.save()
            return redirect("/projects/"+project.ref+"/info/#tabr2", project.ref)

        else:
            return render_to_response('projects/add_test_setup.html', {'testsetupform':testsetupform,'project':project}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

These are the models:

```
class Project(models.Model):

    STATUS_CHOICES = ((0,'Not started'),(1,'ZERO'),(2,'KOM'))

    ref         = models.CharField(max_length=70, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(_("Description"),max_length=170, blank=True)
    notes       = models.TextField(max_length=170,blank=True)
    customer    = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    operator    = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    supervisor  = models.CharField(max_length=70, blank=True)
    start_date  = models.DateField(blank=True,null=True)
    finish_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    status      = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=STATUS_CHOICES[0][1])
    goal        = models.TextField(max_length=170, blank=True)


class TestSetup(models.Model):

    ref         = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
    notes       = models.TextField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
    project     = models.ForeignKey(Project)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "Test set-up %s" % (self.ref)
```

I do not have any problems with the addition of new TestSetups, but when I edit a TestSetup, it throws 404 "No Project matches the given query". At first, I thought that the problem was the `get_object_or_404` of the view, but then I commented this code and replaced it with `Project.objects.get(id=int(project_id))`. Nothing happened.

This is the part of the HTML code where I do the edition of the testsetupform:

```
<form class="vertical" method="post" action="{% url 'edit_test_setup' testsetupform.instance.project.id testsetupform.instance.id %}"> {% csrf_token %}

    {{testsetupform}}

    <h6 style="margin-top:30px">Assign series <span class="tooltip" title="Assign series to this test set-up."><i class="fa fa-question-circle" style="cursor:pointer;color:green;"></i></span></h6>
    <hr class="alt1" />

    <input type="submit" class="button blue" value="Save" style="margin-top:30px"></input>
</form>
```

Also, in the 404 page, this appears:

```
Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/projects/5/testSetup/16/edit/
```

Therefore, both the Project(id=5) and the TestSetup(id=16) models exist! I have tested with other Project models and throws the same error.

----------- EDITION.1 ------------

In addition, using `./manage.py shell`:

```
>>> from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
>>> from projects.models import Project
>>>
>>> project = get_object_or_404(Project, pk=5)
>>> project
<Project: 182TRE>
>>> Project.objects.get(id=5)
<Project: 182TRE>
>>>
```

----------- END OF EDITION.1 ------------

Where could be the problem??

----------- EDITION.2 ------------

I am using `render_to_string` shortcut in the HTML form. This shortcut is called when I edit a TestSetup. What I have is a principal template with a DIV where I load an additional template to edit these TestSetups. This is the AJAX call I use to request this template:

```
function loadTestSetup(setup_id){

    $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url : '/projects/testSetup/'+ setup_id + '/load/',
         data: "",
         dataType: 'text',
         success : function (data, textStatus, request) {
             data = eval("(" + data + ")");
             $("#testsetupedit-dialog").html(data.html)  // "testsetupedit-dialog" is a div of the original template.
         }
    });

}
```

This AJAX call requests a template through this view:

```
def load_test_setup(request, setup_id):

    testSetup = get_object_or_404(TestSetup, pk=int(setup_id))
    setupform = TestSetupForm(None, instance=testSetup)

    data = {'html':""}

    data['html'] = render_to_string('projects/test_setup_form.html', {'setupform':setupform}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(data))
```

with this url pattern:

```
url(r'^testSetup/(?P<setup_id>\w+)/load/$', load_test_setup, name="load_test_setup"),
```

Could I be doing bad use of `render_to_string`?

----------- END OF EDITION.2 ------------

Comment: Did you get `ObjectDoesNotExist` exception  when you replace `get_object_or_404` with `Project.objects.get(id=int(project_id))`?

Comment: Nothing. The same 404 error, no `ObjectDoesNotExist` exception.

Answer (score 0):

You receive 404 error after redirect.
This line:

```
return redirect("/projects/"+testsetup.project.ref+"/info/#tabr2", testsetup.project.ref)
```

Or this line:

```
return redirect("/projects/"+project.ref+"/info/#tabr2", project.ref)
```

Redirects you to wrong URL and you get 404.

Suggestions:

1. Check what URLs is generated in this lines, make sure that their are registered in your project.
2. (Better) Use `django.core.urlresolvers.reverse` to generate URL for redirect. It will raise more meaningful exception if URL is not registered.

Comment: This is not the error, as I have used these lines in other views successfully. I'm editing the question adding some new information that could be critical.